# Upgrading from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics not showing in Firebase Console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am attempting to upgrade from fabric to firebase crashlytics but the despite crashes, my app does not seems to show up in firebase crashlytics console

After having done extensive search on stackoverflow i suspect this is the problem. Though i haven't been able to find an exact solution.

In my build Log i am getting

```
2021-06-07 03:28:24.577430+0200 MyApp[57104:1303300] 6.17.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
2021-06-07 03:28:24.577558+0200 My App[57104:1303300] 6.17.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting async /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CFBECA36-50CB-435E-9CE5-8A17123EFD86/data/Containers/Data/Application/2BADF8CF-1ED3-4B97-85A0-63889A6B7C77/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/MyApp.dev/v4/reports/prepared/D7EED1DE-D3C8-434C-938C-8B6D535AC897.multipartmime
```

This should also have something like

```
completed submission
```

in the Log however i am not getting this message.

So basically any kind of help here would be really appreciated or even how can i get more information to find the root cause of this problem.

Comment: Add more details like implementation code and run scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That version of the Crashlytics SDK "6.17.0" is very old and no longer supported. Try running "pod update" to get the latest version.

Comment: You are right Firebase documentation was indicating that the minimum supported version for crashlytics in console was 4.0 and my crashlytics version was 4.0.0-beta5 but apparently that was not enough. As soon as i updated to the latest version everything started working.